# Couldn't change date to french even if locale is 'fr' in twig symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, date, twig

**In config.yml**

```
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
services: 
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**In twig view**

```
{{ 'now' | localizeddate('full', 'none') }} // returns full date in english
```

What is the problem because I have already set locale and default_locale into fr though it returns always date in English.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the php7.0-intl extension (or for other php version)?

Comment: Oh no. The problem is really from that. thank you @Pec